# android film/switch from back and front camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to film a movie using [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and switching from front camera to back camera and vice versa while recording.

The problem is that I cannot set the camera in the *MediaRecorder* to the new camera, because it will crash due to invalid state.

Any ideas? I am not interested in using Camera2 from API 21, need it for older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to switch the camera of MediaRecorder while in the middle of recording.  The settings of MediaRecorder, including the source of video data, can only be changed before recording starts.

If you need a feature like this, you need to use the lower-level APIs such as MediaCodec, which are more flexible (but require more work to use).